# Address sanitizer stack-use-after-scope with std::format_args

Tags: c++, c++20, address-sanitizer, stdformat

I am getting a stack-use-after-scope error when trying to use `std::format_args` along with `std::vformat()`.  A simple code to reproduce it is:

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    std::string s = "hello";
    std::format_args args = std::make_format_args(i, s);
    std::cout << std::vformat("Number: {}, Word: {}", args) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

My `i` and `s` variables should still be in scope and are not r-values, so I'm not sure what is triggering the error.  If I remove `args` and make a call to `std::make_format_args()` directly in the call to `std::vformat()`, everything works as expected.  What am I missing?

Here is my command to compile the above code: `clang++-17 --std=c++23 -stdlib=libc++ -fsanitize=address fmt.cpp`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::make_format_args(i, s);` does not return `std::format_args args`. The result of the unspecified type can be implicitly converted to `std::format_args args` that keeps a dangling reference to some internal state in the returned temporary object.

The proper usage is:

```
auto args = std::make_format_args(i, s);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Tozs7a9bP

The better usage is:

```
std::cout << std::vformat("Number: {}, Word: {}", std::make_format_args(i, s)) << '\n';
```